Efficiently Implement a Data Transformation || Pytorch || coding advice
I have created the following class and function to create a 'custom' dataset. The use case was to sample every nth image from a data set to reduce the size of the data set while still maintaining representation from all the classes.
I tried subsetting and other similar techniques but these wouldn't have maintained the integrity across the various classes and the lost the index when implemented into a DataLoader. It works but it is neither neat nor tidy and takes some time to implement.
If anyone has any advice on how to tidy this up and consequently speed it up I would be forever grateful.
# Create a class to instantiate a dataset for use in a dataloader
class Cust_Ds(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, features, target):
        super().__init__()
        self.features = features
        self.target = target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.features)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        X = self.features[idx]
        y = self.target[idx]

        return X, y


def custom_length_df(data_set, every_nth_entry):
  red_ls_x = []
  red_ls_y = []
  p = range(0,len(data_set), every_nth_entry)
  for i in p:
    X, Y = data_set[i]
    x = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(Y)
    Xt = torch.Tensor(x)
    Yt = torch.Tensor(y)
    red_ls_x.append(Xt)
    red_ls_y.append(Yt)
  dataset = Cust_Ds(red_ls_x, red_ls_y)

  return dataset


Implementation is as follows:
trg_dataset = custom_length_df(trg_101, 10)
val_dataset = custom_length_df(trg_101, 37)
print(len(trg_dataset))
print(len(val_dataset))

